# How can I remove an extra line from a figure made by matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How can I make two plots on Matplotlib where each plot has a bar chart and a line joining points? Namely, I have bar datas in variables `nollat` and `ykkoset` and line datas from variables `selnollat` and `selykkoset`. I would like to make two files, each one that has one bar chart and one line segment data. The following is the part of the code. I saw that the file `eka.png` seems to be correct but `toka.png` has an extra line (the blue one). How can I remove it?

```
ax = plt.gca()
alanolla = min(nollat)
alayks = min(ykkoset)
ylanolla = max(nollat)
ylayks = max(ykkoset)

ax.set_ylim([0.9*min(alanolla,alayks),1.1*max(ylanolla,ylayks)])
num_bins = len(nollat)
plt.plot(range(len(selnollat)), selnollat)
plt.bar(range(len(nollat)), nollat, color = 'C1')
plt.savefig('eka.png')

ax.set_ylim([0.9*min(alanolla,alayks),1.1*max(ylanolla,ylayks)])
num_bins = len(ykkoset)
plt.plot(range(len(selykkoset)), selykkoset)
plt.bar(range(len(ykkoset)), ykkoset, color = 'C1')
plt.savefig('toka.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `plt.cla()` to clear the content of the axes after you save your first plot

```
...
plt.savefig('eka.png')
plt.cla()

ax.set_ylim([0.9*min(alanolla,alayks),1.1*max(ylanolla,ylayks)])
...
```